# Get the text and remove all tags but retain tags for the titles and bolds

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting the texts from a website using the `text = soup.find('div', class_="entity").get_text(" ")` , but there are some tags/titles (`<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>`) which i want to store them with the tag. I was initially were using a list to keep the track of the titles and add the tag after scraping, but I think there should be a more efficient way?

Saying this is the input:

```
<p> This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
<p> This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>
```

The output should be something like this:

```
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a tag's children have bold content and then choose to store the text or the tag itself. You can iterate over a tag’s children using the *[.children](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)* generator. You may also want to consider using *[.descendants](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants)* if the bold content may appear further nested.

> The `.contents` and `.children` attributes only consider a tag’s direct children.
>   The `.descendants` attribute lets you iterate over all of a tag’s children, recursively: its direct children, the children of its direct children...

You can check if the child is a `Tag` and if so, check if it is a `<b>` tag. You can use [*.name*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name) on a `Tag` to get it's name.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
html = """
<p> This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
<p> This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


def has_bold_content(tag):
    for child in tag.children:
        if isinstance(child, Tag):
            if child.name =='b':
                return True
    return False


output_list = []
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    if has_bold_content(tag):
        # or str(tag) if you just want a string representation
        output_list.append(tag)
    else:
        output_list.append(tag.text)

for i in output_list:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using right CSS selector and use bs4 `.unwrap()` method (This will eplace a tag with whatever’s inside that tag):

```
data = '''<p>This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
<p>This is a normal text; neither bold or italic</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for p_only_tags in soup.select('p:not(:has(b))'):
    p_only_tags.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
<p><b>Micro customers:</b></p>
This is a normal text; neither bold or italic
```

---

CSS selector `p:not(:has(b))` will select all `<p>` which don't contain `<b>` tag. If you want to be more specific, you can use `'p:not(:has(> b))'` - this will select all `<p>` tags which don't contain `<b>` *directly* after them.